# Getting "Insufficient Permission" error while trying to upload a file to GCP using correct credentials with php code

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to upload file to GCP storage. I generated the service credentials. But while using this credential with php code, I get following error.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Google\\Cloud\\Core\\Exception\\ServiceException: {\n  "error": {\n    "code": 403,\n    "message": "Insufficient Permission",\n    "errors": [\n      {\n        "message": "Insufficient Permission",\n        "domain": "global",\n        "reason": "insufficientPermissions"\n      }\n    ]\n  }\n}\n in /var/www/html/Scope/admin/excel/vendor/google/cloud-core/src/RequestWrapper.php:368\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/Scope/admin/excel/vendor/google/cloud-core/src/RequestWrapper.php(207): Google\\Cloud\\Core\\RequestWrapper->convertToGoogleException()\n#1 /var/www/html/Scope/admin/excel/vendor/google/cloud-core/src/Upload/MultipartUploader.php(44): Google\\Cloud\\Core\\RequestWrapper->send()\n#2 /var/www/html/Scope/admin/excel/vendor/google/cloud-storage/src/Bucket.php(294): Google\\Cloud\\Core\\Upload\\MultipartUploader->upload()\n#3 /var/www/html/Scope/admin/excel/create_excel.php(49): Google\\Cloud\\Storage\\Bucket->upload()\n#4 /var/www/html/Scope/admin/excel/create_excel.php(251): uploadFile()\n#5 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/Scope/admin/excel/vendor/google/cloud-core/src/RequestWrapper.php on line 368
```

**create_excle.php** file looks like this.

```
<?php


require 'vendor/autoload.php';

error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);


use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;

$privateKeyFileContent = file_get_contents('5yearfin-excel-uploader.json');
error_log("CONTENT OF PRIVATE KEY IS ");
error_log($privateKeyFileContent);


function uploadFile($bucketName, $fileContent, $cloudPath) {
    // $privateKeyFileContent = $GLOBALS['privateKeyFileContent'];
    // connect to Google Cloud Storage using private key as authentication
    $storage = "";
    try {
        $storage = new StorageClient([
            'keyFile' => json_decode($privateKeyFileContent, true),
            'projectId' => "vera-test-263610"
        ]);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // maybe invalid private key ?
        // print $e;
        error_log("\n\n\nError with the key i suppose .");
        error_log($e);
        return false;
    }
    
    // set which bucket to work in
    $bucket = $storage->bucket($bucketName);
    
    // upload/replace file 
    $storageObject = $bucket->upload(
            $fileContent,
            ['name' => $cloudPath]
            
    );
    
    // is it succeed ?
    error_log(json_encode($storageObject));
    if($storageObject != null){
        error_log("file uploaded successfully");
        error_log("Success to uplaod ". $cloudPath.PHP_EOL);

    }else{
        error_log("\n\n\nFailed to upload");


    };
}

$fileContent = file_get_contents('output.log');
$buckertName = "company-in-progress";
$success = uploadFile($buckertName ,$fileContent, "output.log");
error_log("file upload = " .$success);
http_response_code(200);
echo "Probably file uploaded";


?>
```

The file I am trying to upload is a simple text file named **output.log**.

***I have also tried to do the same thing with python code, with the same credential json file. It works fine.***

I think there is some logical error in my php code. Please help me find it out.

I can assure you that, the credentials json file is read properly. And the bucket is already there on the cloud named "company-in-progress".

Comment: 1) Tip: Use `KeyFilePath` instead of` KeyFile` This simplifies your code plus minimize globals with secrets. 2) Your code is reporting an unhandled exception. Add exception handling so that you know where the exception is occurring which is most likely `$bucket->upload()`. 3) Your problem is probably the wrong Project ID or the wrong Bucket Name.